# signals not working in my vendor management app django app and i tried to import vendor_app.signals in app.py but error is showing

Tags: python, django

I have create three models vendor, purchase order and historical performance where historical performance model update from changes and values of purchase order for which i created signal file seprately and added the logic to update fields.I tried to configure signals in my apps.py file in vendor_app directory for which i am getting error"no module fine vendor_app" . I added vendor_app in my vendor_management/settings.installed app. I can't figure out where is problem.

models.py code

````
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.dispatch import receiver
import datetime
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


# Creating Model for storing user token
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


# Creating model for vendor
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    contact_details = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()
    vendor_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    on_time_delivery = models.FloatField(default=0)
    quality_rating_avg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    average_response_time = models.FloatField(default=0)
    fulfillment_rate = models.FloatField(default=0)


# Creating model for Purchase Order

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('completed', 'Completed'),
        ('canceled', 'Canceled'),
    ]

    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime)
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    items = models.JSONField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    quality_rating = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    issue_date = models.DateTimeField()
    acknowledgment_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


class HistoricalPerformance(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    on_time_delivery_rate = models.FloatField()
    quality_rating_avg = models.FloatField()
    average_response_time = models.FloatField()
    fulfillment_rate = models.FloatField()```

signals.py code
```from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import PurchaseOrder, HistoricalPerformance
from datetime import timezone
from django.db import models


@receiver(post_save, sender=PurchaseOrder)
def update_vendor_performance(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    def calculate_on_time_delivery_rate(vendor):
        completed_purchases = PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(vendor=vendor, status='completed')
        on_time_deliveries = completed_purchases.filter(acknowledgment_date__lte=models.F('delivery_date'))
        total_completed_purchases = completed_purchases.count()
        if total_completed_purchases == 0:
            return 0.0
        return on_time_deliveries.count() / total_completed_purchases

    #other logic function.... 

    if created and instance.status == 'completed':
       
        on_time_delivery_rate = calculate_on_time_delivery_rate(instance.vendor)
        quality_rating_avg = calculate_quality_rating_avg(instance.vendor)
        average_response_time = calculate_average_response_time(instance.vendor)
        fulfillment_rate = calculate_fulfillment_rate(instance.vendor)
        # Update or create a HistoricalPerformance record
        HistoricalPerformance.objects.update_or_create(
            vendor=instance.vendor,
            date=timezone.now(),
            on_time_delivery_rate=on_time_delivery_rate,
            quality_rating_avg=quality_rating_avg,
            average_response_time=average_response_time,
            fulfillment_rate=fulfillment_rate
        )
        print("signal working")
````